# GNUPlot combining loops and column scaling

Tags: loops, variables, gnuplot, scaling

I have a dataset with multiple columns of data, which I plot using a loop

```
plot for [i=2:19] 'myfile.txt' using 1:i
```

I would like to scale my data by dividing by 1024. Outside of a loop I can do this with:

```
plot 'myfile.txt' using 1:($2/1024)
```

I would like to combine these two, but the following does not work:

```
plot for [i=2:19] 'myfile.txt' using 1:($i/1024)
```

I imagine it is to do with the order that the substitutions are happening in.

Can any one show me an elegant solution here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `column(i)` instead of `$i`:

```
plot for [i=2:19] 'myfile.txt' using 1:(column(i)/1024.)
```

should work.